# Google Chart refresh freezes page/div + insufficient memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-visualization

So I have been playing around with google chart for a dashboard I am making using python and web.py. I got it to work to show everything as I want to and technically it works. However the auto refresh of the google chart hangs my page during the ajax calls, and as I may have multiple charts on 1 page it is really bad (getting 1 sec of normal movement and then a few seconds of processing time on the graphs which freeze the page).
After a while it stops working and shows me the insufficient resources error.

Could someone take a look at the code below and show me where this is going wrong. Note that my ajax call is done async now, which only freezes the div, but I still get the error.
Also note the code is from web.py template system, hence some javascript calls have 2 dollar signs in front.

Thanks!

```
$def with (cpuUsage, nodes)

<div id="cpu_usage_graphs">

</div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script>
        // load chart lib
        //google.load('visualization', '1', {
        //  packages: ['corechart']
        //});
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});

        var nodes = $:nodes;
        var graphRow = document.getElementById("cpu_usage_graphs");
        $$.each(nodes, function(i, node) {
            graphRow.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="col-lg-6"><div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> CPU Usage for Node ' + node.hostName + '</h3></div><div id="CPU_Usage' + node.nodeId + '" class="panel-body"></div></div></div>');

            // call drawChart once google charts is loaded
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                // JSONP request
                var jsonData = $$.ajax({
                  url: 'http://192.168.1.100:5051/CPU_Usage?node=' + node.nodeId,
                  type: 'GET',
                  async: true,
                  dataType: 'json',
                }).done(function (results) {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'cpu usage');

                    $$.each(results[0], function (i, row) {
                        data.addRow([
                        (new Date(row.timestamp)),
                        parseFloat(row.value),
                        ]);
                      });

                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($$('#CPU_Usage' + node.nodeId).get(0));

                    chart.draw(data, {
                        'legend':'left',
                      });

                    }).fail(function()  {
                        console.log("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                    }); 
                setInterval(refreshData, 5000);
              }

            function refreshData () {
                drawChart();
            }

            //refreshData();
        });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the resources are most likely being drained due to the number of `setInterval` calls

each interval is interfering with the next and there aren't enough resources to complete them all

also, google's `setOnLoadCallback` is typically only used once per page load,
it isn't needed after the first callback finishes

recommend placing the callback in the `load` statement instead

recommend setup as follows, only 1 `setInterval` is used to re-draw all the charts...

note: 5 seconds seems a little quick to begin re-drawing, recommend allowing enough time for all the charts to finish drawing before starting the next round...

```
$def with (cpuUsage, nodes)

<div id="cpu_usage_graphs">

</div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script>
        google.charts.load('current', {
          callback: function () {
            var nodes = $:nodes;
            var graphRow = document.getElementById("cpu_usage_graphs");

            function drawCharts() {
              $$.each(nodes, function(i, node) {
                if (document.getElementById('CPU_Usage' + node.nodeId) === null) {
                  graphRow.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="col-lg-6"><div class="panel panel-primary"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> CPU Usage for Node ' + node.hostName + '</h3></div><div id="CPU_Usage' + node.nodeId + '" class="panel-body"></div></div></div>');
                }

                $$.ajax({
                  url: 'http://192.168.1.100:5051/CPU_Usage?node=' + node.nodeId,
                  type: 'GET',
                  async: true,
                  dataType: 'json',
                }).done(function (results) {
                  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
                  data.addColumn('number', 'cpu usage');

                  $$.each(results[0], function (i, row) {
                    data.addRow([
                      (new Date(row.timestamp)),
                      parseFloat(row.value),
                    ]);
                  });

                  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($$('#CPU_Usage' + node.nodeId).get(0));
                  chart.draw(data, {
                    'legend':'left',
                  });
                }).fail(function()  {
                  console.log("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
                });
              });
            }

            drawCharts();
            setInterval(drawCharts, 5000);
          },
          packages: ['corechart']
        });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At fist glance this seems to be working. I have it implemented and it has been running for a few minutes now too. I'll mark this as solved and hope no issues will come back :)
Thanks!